# AND occasionally produces wrong result on shell and node native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I’ve built a dynamic query generator to create my desired queries based on many factors, however, in rare cases it acted weird. After a day on reading logs I found a situation that can be simplified in this:

```
db.users.find({att: ‘a’, att: ‘b’})
```

What I expect is that mongodb by default uses AND, so above query’s result should be an empty array. However, it’s not!
But when I use AND explicitly, the result is an empty array

```
db.users.find({$and: [{att: 'a'}, {att: ‘b'}]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript object’s keys should be unique, otherwise the value will be replaced by the latest value
(also mongodb shell is based on js, so it follows some rules of js)

```js
const t = {att: 'a', att: 'b'};
console.log(t);
```

So in your case your query is acting like this:

```
db.users.find({att: ‘b’})
```

You’ve to handle this situation on your code if you want the result be empty in the  mentioned condition